# Python UnicodeEncodeError using PyCrypto on App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to pass an encrypted query string to another URL.

The following code gives me this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u04b7' in
>   position 7: ordinal not in range(128)

The encryption module is [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/)

Running Python 2.5.2 on App Engine

#### PAGE A

```
    import Crypto
    from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4

    obj=ARC4.new('stackoverflow')
    msg = 'This is my secret msg'
    encrypted = obj.encrypt(msg);

    self.redirect('/pageb?' + urllib.urlencode({'q': encrypted}))
```

#### PAGE B

```
    import Crypto
    from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4

    encrypted = self.request.get('q')
    obj=ARC4.new('stackoverflow')
    decrypted = obj.decrypt(encrypted)

    get_data = cgi.parse_qs(decrypted)

    self.response.out.write(decrypted)
    self.response.out.write(pprint.pprint(get_data))
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\_webapp25.py", line 701, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\demos\guestbook\guestbook.py", line 47, in get
    decrypted = obj.decrypt(encrypted)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u04b7' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: This appears to be a statement of fact, with minimum collateral. Try asking a question, supported by useful information, like a traceback.

Comment: The information is there now, but the question is still implied at best.

Comment: Why are you redirecting to another URL in your own application, trying to encrypt things between requests, instead of just calling the required internal API bits in your request or storing the sensitive information server-side with session control? This seems needlessly complex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

General guidelines: add base64 encoding/decoding step in your encrypted stuff.

```
import base64

base64_encrypted_message = base64.b64encode(encrypted_message)
// send your message via POST as GET can be seen on system logs

encrypted_message = base64.b64decode(base64_encrypted_message)
// decrypt your message
```

For the other error, try reading up on [unicode & utf-8](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/) encoding of non-ascii characters. You need this step before passing it to your de/encrypt function.

Comment: John Machin mentioned base64 but you're answer was more direct.

Answer (score 1):

All that can be deduced from the information available is that something is expecting a bytestring but you have fed it a `unicode` object containing the Unicode character U+04B7 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER CHE WITH DESCENDER ... this is of course not encodable in ASCII (the default encoding), hence the error message.

Best possible answer so far: Don't do that.

**Update 1:** You still haven't asked a question. Nonetheless:

So "something" is some crypto gadget's `decrypt` method. That surely needs a `str` object. What does `print repr(encrypted)` tell you? If it looks like random rubbish (as encrypted stuff should), then somehow it has been converted from a `str` object to a `unicode` object. You need to back-track to see how this is happening. If `encrypted` looks like meaningful text, then your encryption process is broken.

Step 1: Start with some known plaintext, encrypt it, and decrypt it again in a simple script outside the GAE apparatus. Use print repr() at each stage so that you have reasonable expectations for the next step.

Step 2: Repeat step 1 using GAE, inspecting the type and contents of each piece of data.

**Update 2** It appears that you have a `urlencode` in page A, but no corresponding `urldecode` in page B; is this (part of) the problem?

Comment: I change the msg to something else, "hello" and the error went away, but I'm still getting the decrypted, it's empty.

How do you send an encrypted message between URLs?

I'm very new to python (started days ago) I normally use PHP so i'm very limited.

I guess this is why PHP dominated the web because it doesn't take days of researching/headaches to encode/decode a simple string.

Comment: Ok, let me try that and get back to you. Thanks.

PS: I have already tried outputting the encrypted directly and I did get giberish including a lot of black diamond character with a questionmark on it.

Comment: Here is the output of repr(encrypted): '\xf0"\xfe\xe8I)\x0bxCq\xd1\x1e\xa1v\xc38\xb1\xd2\xb7^\x85'

Comment: You send an encrypted message between 2 URLs the same way you send any bytestring anywhere: suitably protected against munging by some armourplate like base64 and then removing the armourplate on arrival. You don't need "days of researching/headaches to encode/decode a simple string" in any language. You do need a methodical way of problem solving in any language.

Comment: Your "output of repr(encrypted)" is from page A or page B???? What plain-text input???? It certainly doesn't look like it contains `\x04\xb7` anywhere.

Comment: I encrypted/decrypted on the same page for that time. input text was 'This is my secret msg'

Comment: By the way the code i'm using I got from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794942/crypto-pycrypto-with-google-app-engine/2795254#2795254

Comment: Basically I'm trying to replicate that but it's just not working on my end, but it must work because it was selected best answer on that question.

Comment: Also, urllib has urlencode but apparently not urldecode:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urldecode'